# Flutter:Testing the widget with circular progress indicator and api call using Dio

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-test

How to write widget test for the form which is built based on the api call until then the circular progress indicator is shown, i am able to write it but it is working ony if the API call returns null,if the ApI returns a proper response and in setState() the value is setted for the form to render the UI, the widget testing fails.How can i overcome this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```dart
await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: x));
```

followed by your widget test

`x` = approx sec to get response from api

Comment: this is not how you should test. You should mock your api. and test your widgets with mocked data.